# Azure - Arm Template - Scheduled Query Error

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have a strange error while using arm template to create a Schedule Query.

> properties.search.query is not a valid log metric query.It should contain 'AggregatedValue' and 'bin(timestamp, )' for log metric query

No search property found in documentation or samples

template

```
{
    location: "****",
    "properties": {
        "description": "****",
        "enabled": "true",
        "source": {
            "query": "exceptions",
            "authorizedResources": [],
            "dataSourceId": "/subscriptions/****",
            "queryType": "ResultCount"
        },
        "schedule": {
            "frequencyInMinutes": 5,
            "timeWindowInMinutes": 5
        },
        "action": {
            "odata.type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.Microsoft.AppInsights.Nexus.DataContracts.Resources.ScheduledQueryRules.AlertingAction",
            "severity": "1",
            "aznsAction": {
                "actionGroup": [ "/subscriptions/****" ]
            },
            "trigger": {
                "thresholdOperator": "GreaterThan",
                "threshold": 3,
                "metricTrigger": {
                    "thresholdOperator": "GreaterThan",
                    "threshold": 5,
                    "metricTriggerType": "Consecutive",
                    "metricColumn": "ColumnName"
                }
            }
        }
    },
}
```

Happens also when i use samples from 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/scheduledqueryrules/createorupdate

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you use this section:

```
"metricTrigger":
{
"thresholdOperator": "GreaterThan",
"threshold": 5,
"metricTriggerType": "Consecutive",
"metricColumn": "ColumnName"
}
```

You should remove the whole "metricTrigger" in your scenario.